# How to make xkeyval accept a value containing both \par and a comma

Tags: xkeyval

I am writing a package and I would ideally like to save long stretches of code using the key-value mechanism of `xkeyval`.  That is, I want to be able to say something like

```
\setkeys{foo}{mytext={This is some long text, 
                      including multiple paragraphs.

                      Here is the second paragraph.}}
```

and have the `mytext` key do some processing or manipulation.  I have no problems when the value includes a `\par` token, and I have no problems when it includes a comma, but when it includes both I get an error message.  Here's a minimal (non-)working example:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{xkeyval}

\makeatletter
\define@key{ABC}{mykey}{\long\def\mymacro{#1}}

\begin{document}

%\setkeys{ABC}{mykey={DE,F}}     % This line works.
%\setkeys{ABC}{mykey={D\par EF}} % This line works.
\setkeys{ABC}{mykey={D\par E,F}} % This line doesn't work.

\mymacro

\end{document}
```

It produces the error message

```
Runaway argument?
{mykey={D
! Paragraph ended before \@s@l@ctive@sanitize was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.11 \setkeys{ABC}{mykey={D\par E,F}}

?
```

I'm guessing that when `xkeyval` sees a comma in a key's value, it invokes sanitizing macros which aren't defined as `long`; a quick glance at `xkvutils.tex` seems to confirm my suspicion.

Is there a way for an `xkeyval` key-value pair to include both a `\par` and a comma?

Answer (score 2):

Since `xkeyval` doesn't expand the keyvalues, it's possible to store the 'offending' part with `D\par E,F` to a macro, say, `\myarg`. This will work then.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{xkeyval}

\makeatletter
\define@key{ABC}{mykey}{\long\def\mymacro{#1}}

\newcommand{\myarg}{D\par E,F}
\begin{document}

%\setkeys{ABC}{mykey={DE,F}}     % This line works.
%\setkeys{ABC}{mykey={D\par EF}} % This line works.
%\setkeys{ABC}{mykey={{D\protect\par E},F}} % This line doesn't work.

\setkeys{ABC}{mykey={\myarg}}
\mymacro



\end{document}
```

Comment: That works in a way, I suppose, but it's not quite satisfying.  I was hoping to keep my package code clean by being able to take user input from a macro I'm writing and pass it to xkeyval; for example, `\long\def\usermacro#1#2#3{\setkeys{ABC}{mykey={#1},myotherkey={#2}}\dosomethingelse{#3}}`.  If I have to add the "wrapper" `\myarg` as you suggest, I might as well simply write `\long\def\usermacro#1#2#3{\long\def\mymacro{#1}\setkeys{ABC}{myotherkey={#2}}\dosomethingelse{#3}}`.  It works just fine, but since I'm using `xkeyval` for other arguments, I was hoping to keep a parallel structure.

Comment: @AndersHendrickson: There might be other (and better) solutions, but your question isn't really precise.

Comment: That's fair.  I guess what I'm really hoping for is a patch for `xkeyval` that would let it accept both the `\par` and the comma without any intermediate steps.  I think I've got one worked up, and I'll try to put it below.

Answer (score 0):

Christian Hupfer's comment above helped me clarify for myself that I really wanted to just make `xkeyval` work the way I wanted, accepting both a `\par` and a comma, without any extra intervention required on the part of the end user or a package author.  After spending a week trying to understand the code in `xkvutils.tex` in idle minutes, I came up with the following code to redefine a few macros of `xkeyval`:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{xkeyval}
\makeatletter

\long\def\@s@lective@sanitize[#1]#2#3{%
  \begingroup
    \count@#1\relax\advance\count@\@ne
    \XKV@toks\expandafter{#3}%
    \def#3{#2}\@onelevel@sanitize#3%
    \edef#3{{#3}{\the\XKV@toks}}%
    \expandafter\@s@l@ctive@sanitize\expandafter#3#3%
    \expandafter\XKV@tempa@toks\expandafter{#3}%
  \expandafter\endgroup\expandafter\toks@\expandafter{\the\XKV@tempa@toks}%
  \edef#3{\the\toks@}%
}
\long\def\@s@l@ctive@sanitize#1#2#3{%
  \def\@i{\futurelet\@@tok\@ii}%
  \def\@ii{%
    \ifx\@@tok\@s@l@ctive@sanitize
      \let\@@cmd\@gobble
    \else
      \expandafter\@iii\meaning\@@tok\relax
      \ifx\@@tok\@sptoken
        \XKV@toks\expandafter{#1}\edef#1{\the\XKV@toks\space}%
        \def\@@cmd{\afterassignment\@i\let\@@tok= }%
      \else
        \let\@@cmd\@iv
      \fi
    \fi
    \@@cmd
  }%
  \def\@iii##1##2\relax{\if##1\@backslashchar\let\@@tok\relax\fi}%
  \long\def\@iv##1{%
    \toks@\expandafter{#1}\XKV@toks{##1}%
    \ifx\@@tok\bgroup
      \advance\count@\m@ne
      \ifnum\count@>\z@
        \begingroup
          \def#1{\expandafter\@s@l@ctive@sanitize
            \csname\string#1\endcsname{#2}}%
          \expandafter#1\expandafter{\the\XKV@toks}%
          \XKV@toks\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
            {\csname\string#1\endcsname}%
          \edef#1{\noexpand\XKV@toks{\the\XKV@toks}}%
        \expandafter\endgroup#1%
      \fi
      \edef#1{\the\toks@{\the\XKV@toks}}%
      \advance\count@\@ne
      \let\@@cmd\@i
    \else
      \edef#1{\expandafter\string\the\XKV@toks}%
      \expandafter\in@\expandafter{#1}{#2}%
      \edef#1{\the\toks@\ifin@#1\else
              \ifx\@@tok\@sptoken\space\else\the\XKV@toks\fi\fi}%
      \edef\@@cmd{\noexpand\@i\ifx\@@tok\@sptoken\the\XKV@toks\fi}%
    \fi
    \@@cmd
  }%
  \let#1\@empty\@i#3\@s@l@ctive@sanitize
}

\define@key{ABC}{mykey}{\long\def\mymacro{#1}}

\begin{document}

%\setkeys{ABC}{mykey={DE,F}}     % This line works.
%\setkeys{ABC}{mykey={D\par EF}} % This line works.
\setkeys{ABC}{mykey={D\par E,F}} % This line now works.
\mymacro

%It can still handle conditionals.
\setkeys{ABC}{mykey={\ifnum1<2\relax True \else False\fi}}
{\tt\meaning\mymacro}

\end{document}
```

The only change to `\@s@lective@sanitize` is making it a `\long` macro.  The interior macro `\@s@l@ctive@sanitize` required a little more work.  In case anyone's interested in the details, here is the original code for comparison:

```
\def\@s@l@ctive@sanitize#1#2#3{%
  \def\@i{\futurelet\@@tok\@ii}%
  \def\@ii{%
    \expandafter\@iii\meaning\@@tok\relax
    \ifx\@@tok\@s@l@ctive@sanitize
      \let\@@cmd\@gobble
    \else
      \ifx\@@tok\@sptoken
        \XKV@toks\expandafter{#1}\edef#1{\the\XKV@toks\space}%
        \def\@@cmd{\afterassignment\@i\let\@@tok= }%
      \else
        \let\@@cmd\@iv
      \fi
    \fi
    \@@cmd
  }%
  \def\@iii##1##2\relax{\if##1\@backslashchar\let\@@tok\relax\fi}%
  \def\@iv##1{%
    \toks@\expandafter{#1}\XKV@toks{##1}%
    \ifx\@@tok\bgroup
      \tracingmacros=1\relax
      \advance\count@\m@ne
      \ifnum\count@>\z@
        \begingroup
          \def#1{\expandafter\@s@l@ctive@sanitize
            \csname\string#1\endcsname{#2}}%
          \expandafter#1\expandafter{\the\XKV@toks}%
          \XKV@toks\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
            {\csname\string#1\endcsname}%
          \edef#1{\noexpand\XKV@toks{\the\XKV@toks}}%
        \expandafter\endgroup#1%
      \fi
      \edef#1{\the\toks@{\the\XKV@toks}}%
      \advance\count@\@ne
      \let\@@cmd\@i
    \else
      \edef#1{\expandafter\string\the\XKV@toks}%
      \expandafter\in@\expandafter{#1}{#2}%
      \edef#1{\the\toks@\ifin@#1\else
              \ifx\@@tok\@sptoken\space\else\the\XKV@toks\fi\fi}%
      \edef\@@cmd{\noexpand\@i\ifx\@@tok\@sptoken\the\XKV@toks\fi}%
    \fi
    \@@cmd
  }%
  \let#1\@empty\@i#3\@s@l@ctive@sanitize
}
```

Of course `\@s@l@ctive@sanitize` needed to be made `\long` itself, but it defines another macro `\@iv` which also reads tokens to be sanitized, so `\@iv` also needed to be made `\long`.

These changes made sense, but now there was a new problem: the recursion never stopped.  The macro uses itself, `\@s@l@ctive@sanitize`, as the delimiter to let it know when to stop.  First `\@i` uses `\futurelet` to save the next token in `\@@tok`, before `\@ii` takes over.  Then `\@ii` has `\@iii` check whether that next token is a TeX primitive, using the mechanism of asking whether its `\meaning` begins with a backslash; if so, it sets `\@@tok` equal to `\relax`.  (The goal here seems to be to keep conditionals like `\if`, `\else`, and `\fi` from causing trouble by being expanded inside `\@iv`.)   When `\@iii` is done, `\@ii` takes over again, checking whether (a) `\@@tok` is the `\@s@l@ctive@sanitize` at the end of the tokens to be sanitized, in which case we stop the recursion by simply `\@gobble`-ing that `\@s@l@ctive@sanitize` token; (b) `\@@tok` is a space token, which requires special handling; or (c) `\@@tok` is anything else, in which case it gets added to the sanitized list by `\@iv`.

So the new problem is that when we made `\@s@l@ctive@sanitize` long, its `\meaning` has changed from

```
macro: #1#2#3->\def \@i {\futurelet ...
```

to

```
\long macro: #1#2#3->\def \@i {\futurelet ...
```

Now when we reach the end of the sequence of tokens to be sanitized, when `\@@tok` has been `\let` equal to `\@s@l@ctive@sanitize`, `\@iii` tests the meaning of `\@@tok` and sees the backslash of `\long`, believes it has found a TeX primitive to be guarded against, and sets `\@@tok` equal to `\relax`.  Thus when `\@ii` runs `\ifx\@@tok\@s@l@ctive@sanitize`, the conditional evaluates as false, and the recursion never ends.

I fixed this in my patch above by having `\@ii` test for the end-of-recursion marker first, *before* having `\@iii` check for the backslash.

I was little worried about whether this would break anything `\@iii` was supposed to guard against, but so far my new code seems to work as long as the conditionals in the key are balanced, which was needed for `xkeyval` before the patch anyway.  I'll test it a little more, but if anyone sees a problem with my patch or a better solution, please let me know!